# Simple Rails routing situation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a Ruby on Rails app that consists of stories. Each story has multiple pages.

How can I set up routes.rb so that I can have URLs like this:

```
http://mysite.com/[story id]/[page id]
```

Like:

```
http://mysite.com/29/46
```

Currently I'm using this sort of setup:

```
http://mysite.com/stories/29/pages/46
```

Using:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|

  map.resources :stories, :has_many => :pages
  map.resources :pages

  map.root :controller => "stories", :action => "index"

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

end
```

Thanks in advance. I'm a newbie to Rails and routing seems a bit complicated to me right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here's](http://keironwaites.com/2008/10/ruby-on-rails-routing-simple-examples.html) a good resource.

```
map.connect 'stories/:story_id/:page_num', :controller => "stories", :action => "index", :page_id => nil
```

In your controller:

```
def index
  story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
  @page = story.pages[params[:page_num]]
end
```

UPDATE: Just noticed you don't want 'stories' to appear.  Not sure if dropping that from the map.connect will work... try it out.

```
map.connect '/:story_id/:page_num', ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Still working out how exactly to utilize the controller to pull the right page, but you've put me on the right track, at least.

Comment: After reading your update... map.connect '/:story_id/:page_id', ... works well enough (note the slash at the beginning)...but I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Given the route of

```
map.connect '/:story_id/:id', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'show'
```

You could do this in your controller

```
def show
  @story = Story.find(:story_id)
  @page = @story.pages.find(:id)
end
```

Now you can get the page using the story id.

PS: `map.connect ':story_id/:id'` *should* work.

Comment: Your code snippet is not valid -- both your find calls are missing the params hash and just passing the symbol. `Story.find(:story_id)` should be `Story.find(params[:story_id])`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why no one has suggested just using a named route.  Something like

```
map.story '/:story_id/:page_id', :controller => 'stories', :action => 'show'
```

then you could just call it with

```
story_path(story.id,params[:page})
```

or something similar.

Comment: Because Unniloct didn't ask about that, he asked what to do to get the story and page, not link to it.